# Magento 2.1.x Multistore Multi domains, getting 404 error on Product Display Page for non Default Store View

Tags: magento-2.1, 404, product-urls

I have a Magento CE 2.1.4 website, with 2 store views with 2 different domains.

The “Add Store Code to Urls” in Stores > Configuration > General > Web > URL options is set to DISABLED since
I'm using different domain names for the 2 stores.

I have a product that is shared between the 2 stores but has slight details differences that are set the store view scope.
On Default Store, the Product Display Page (PDP) works properly from the category link, and from the direct product URL without
the category path.
On the secondary store, the PDP works fine with the category path, but I get a 404 error when accessing the page without the
category paths.

NOTE:
* The problem also exists in 2.1.9 (dev site)
* Setting the product to use a unique URL key at the secondary store view scope also didn't solve the problem.

Has anyone else run into this issue, and have a resolution?  Thanks in advance for your help?

Test results done on Magento 2.1.9:
Default Store:
OK >>> https://m2dev.**specialized**.net/12v-erv-unit-solarpulse-erv-12v-solar-charger-maintainer-6-watt.html

Even after setting URL to be unique at the secondary Store Scope:
404 ERROR >>> https://m2dev.**pulsetech**.net/12v-erv-unit-solarpulse-erv-12v-solar-charger-maintainer-6-watt-test.html

Comment: URLs with category path work fine on both stores.      Default Store:
OK >>> https://m2dev.specialized.net/store/solar-battery-chargers/12v-solar-chargers/12v-erv-unit-solarpulse-erv-12v-solar-charger-maintainer-6-watt.html

Secondary Store:
OK >>> https://m2dev.pulsetech.net/store/solar-battery-chargers/12v-solar-chargers/12v-erv-unit-solarpulse-erv-12v-solar-charger-maintainer-6-watt-test.html    Thanks in advance.

Comment: One other problem that this issue causes is site search.  We're using the URLs without the category path for the site search service.

Comment: Removing the category path worked for me no 404 from me on this link: https://m2dev.pulsetech.net/store/12v-erv-unit-solarpulse-erv-12v-solar-charger-maintainer-6-watt-test.html

Comment: Please make sure product is assigned with the second store also.

Comment: dawhoo, thank you for pointing out that you got the URL working by removing almost all of the category paths.  However, I noticed that the "/store" path is still part of the URL.  https://m2dev.pulsetech.net/store/12v-erv-unit-solarpulse-erv-12v-solar-charger-maintainer-6-watt-test.html.   Is this just one of those M2 quirks?

Comment: visha, yes, the product is assigned to the second store.

Comment: dawhoo, "Store" is a top category level configured below the secondary store's root category.

Comment: More info >>>  After reviewing the URL rewrite entries, I believe the core issue is why we're getting the 404 error for the secondary store: https://m2dev.pulsetech.net/catalog/product/view/id/15120/

Whereas it works for the primary store:  https://m2dev.specialized.net/catalog/product/view/id/15120/